# protected inheritance - Does the base class constructor protected or the inherited class constructor protected?

Tags: c++, inheritance

let's say I have 2 classes

```
class Employee {//constructor definition};
class Manager : protected Employee{ //constructor definition};
Manager::Manager (string newName, double newPayRate, double newHours, bool newSalariedEmployee): Employee (newName, newPayRate, newHours)
{
    mSalaried = newSalariedEmployee;
}
Employee::Employee (string newName, double newPayRate, double newHours)
{
    mName = newName;
    mPayRate = newPayRate;
    mHours = newHours;
}
int main () 
{
    Employee *pMan = new Manager("bob", 0.5, 98, false); //squishy line
    return 0;
};
```

I know that if i change `protected` to `public`then `Employee *pMan = new Manager("bob", 0.5, 98, false);` will work, but I have other questions 
1. Is the error happens when `new Manager (...)` is called? Because `new` is not a member function of `Manager()`, which mean the process can't be done because `new` doesn't have access to `Manager(...)//default constructor`

2. Or the process can't be done because when it goes to `Manager::Manager (string newName, double newPayRate, double newHours, bool newSalariedEmployee): Employee (newName, newPayRate, newHours)` the `Employee(...)` cannot be invoke due to it public functions are protected? 
Please help me clear things up, thanks!

Comment: You didn't declare the constructors...

Comment: let's pretend it there, my question is the logic behind the error, not the error

Comment: With protected inheritance, outsiders (non-friends, non-members) may not convert a `Manager*` to an `Employee*`.

Comment: No, it matters, because since you're not showing the declarations, it's not immediately obvious that you intended to declare them in the `public:` section. Please don't make your question harder to read than it has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem of constructor inheritance, but relates to the fact that -being the inheritance protected- noting outside `Manager` in fact *knows* about the existence of an `Employee` sub-object.

So casting a `Manager*` (what `new` returns) to an `Employee*` is not possible being the two types publicly unrelated.

Changing protected to public makes the inheritance visible from outside (and hence letting the `Employee` part of `Manager` to be accessible)